# How to use XPATH to find an image called *logo*, or which has a class with the word *logo* in it?

Tags: xpath

I am creating a crawler which needs to download the logo from every website it crawls.

It is quite hard to detect which image is the logo, however I don't need 100% accuracy, so I am thinking of just looking for `<img>` tags which fulfil any of the following conditions:

A. The name of the image in the `<img>` tag has the word "logo" in it, for example:

```
<img src="logo.gif">
<img src="site-logo.jpg">
<img src="mainlogo.png">
```

B. The `class` or `id` in the `<img>` tag has the word logo in it, for example:

```
<img class="logo" src="something.gif">
<img id="main-logo" src="something.gif">
<img class="background logo" src="something.gif">
```

I've tried following the [W3C XPATH documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), but it is not very user friendly. I've also tried using what are supposed to be wildcards (according to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp)) but they do not appear to work as expected.

Is it possible to achieve what I want using XPATH? Could you help provide some pointers or example code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
/html/body//img[contains(@src, 'logo') or contains(@id, 'logo') or contains(@class, 'logo')]
```

which will find all `img` tags that are a descendant of the `body` tag, where the `src`, `id` or `class` attribute contains the text `logo`.

Comment: Why `/html/body//img`? Why not just `//img`? What other `img` tags do you imagine might be erroneously found?

Comment: @Phrogz I figured it would be more efficient if it didn't waste time looking in the `head` tag etc :)